How to use SessionId with ServiceBusOutput on Worker Function azure
I am using .NET Isolated Functions
I need to send multiple messages to a queue
So I am using the code below
[Function("process-duplicates")]
public async Task<DispatchedMessages> ProcessDataAsync([Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous,
        "post", Route = "myroute")]
    HttpRequest req,
    IAsyncCollector<string> asyncCollector)
{
    await _myService.ProcessDataAsync();

    return new DispatchedMessages
    {
        Messages = _myService.MessagesToBeSent.Select(x => x.ToJson()),
        Status = new OkObjectResult("Processed Data")
    };
}

Where DispatchedMessages is
public class DispatchedMessages
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    [ServiceBusOutput("QueueName", Connection = "event-bus-connection")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Messages { get; set; }

    public IActionResult Status { get; set; }

}

This works fine for a normal queue
However, I now need to get this work on a session based queue so I need to provide a value for the sessionId
  var messages = new List<ServiceBusMessage>();

  _myService.MessagesToBeSent.ForEach(x =>
  {
      var message = new ServiceBusMessage(x.ToJson())
      {
        SessionId = "Test"
      };

      messages.Add(message);
    });

    var result = new DispatchedMessages
    {
      Messages = messages.Select(x => x.ToJson()),
      Status = new OkObjectResult("Processed Data")
    };

But this doesnt work
How can I do this?
Paul

There's no IAsyncCollector in the Isolated Worker SDK. You must use ASB SDK types to send messages. See the repo for a similar question.


How to use SessionId with ServiceBusOutput on Worker Function azure

To send messages to service bus with Session Id , you have to use Azure SDK's for it .
Function.cs:
    using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
    
    namespace RithFunctionApp
    {
        public class Function1
        {
            private readonly ILogger<Function1> ri_lg;
            private readonly ServiceBusClient ri_sbc;
    
            public Function1(ILogger<Function1> ri, ServiceBusClient sbc)
            {
                ri_lg = ri;
                ri_sbc = sbc;
            }
    
            [Function("Function1")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
            {
                ri_lg.LogInformation("Hello Rithwik Bojja, Function is sending messages");
                var msg_with_ssId = MessageAndSession();
                await SendMessageToServiceBus(msg_with_ssId);
                return new OkObjectResult("Hello Rithwik Bojja, Sent Message with id, please check");
            }
    
            private List<ListTest> MessageAndSession()
            {
                return new List<ListTest>
                {
                    new ListTest { Msg = "Rithwik", SessId = "Sess-1" },
                    new ListTest { Msg = "Bojja", SessId = "Sess-2" },
                };
            }
    
            private async Task SendMessageToServiceBus(List<ListTest> msgs)
            {
                ServiceBusSender sender = ri_sbc.CreateSender("rithq1");
                foreach (var rith in msgs)
                {
                    var ri_msg = new ServiceBusMessage(rith.Msg)
                    {
                        SessionId = rith.SessId
                    };
                    await sender.SendMessageAsync(ri_msg);
                }
            }
        }
    
        public class ListTest
        {
            public string Msg { get; set; }
            public string SessId { get; set; }
        }
    }

Here rithq1 is queue name.
Program.cs:
    using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    
    var ri = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
        .ConfigureServices(rith =>
        {
            rith.AddSingleton((s) =>
            {
                string rics = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("test");
                return new ServiceBusClient(rics);
            });
        })
        .Build();
    ri.Run();

Here test is connection string stored in local.settings.json.
local.settings.json:
    {
        "IsEncrypted": false,
      "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
        "test": "Endpoint=sb://rithtest.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=6YXOZPAvhY="
      }
    }

Output:



